# Efficient computation of the overlapping between sequences

Tags: python, sequence, overlap, python-3.9

Given two sequences `s1` and `s2`, a *supersequence* of `s1` and `s2` is another sequences with length less than the sum of the lengths of `s1` and `s2` and that contains them. For example, for `s1=[1,2,4,4]`, and `s2=[4,4,9,7]`, a supersequence may be `[1,2,4,4,9,7]`, and also `[1,2,4,4,4,9,7]`.

I am trying to find an efficient implementation of a function `f` whose inputs are two sequences `s1` and `s2` and that does the following: first, compute the number of possible supersequences and then returns the position where the overlapping takes place (for simplicity, let's assume `s1` always appears first in the supersequences).

For instance, taking the previous example, `f([1,2,4,4], [4,4,9,7])` should return `2` and `3`, the indexes where the second sequence starts in the two existing supersequences.

Comment: does s1 and s2 needs to be in order? Or can it be s2 before s1?

Comment: This should be related to [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). It's called [SCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem).

Comment: You could have a look at [these other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Shortest+common+supersequence).

Comment: That's a weird non-standard definition of *supersequence*.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the potential overlap positions with a list comprehension based on enumerate of the left side list.

```
idx = [ i for i,v1 in enumerate(s1) if v1==s2[0] ]

# [2, 3]
```

However, I would suggest a different overall strategy using a recursive generator to produce all the supersequences.

```
def superpose(s1,s2,inverted=False):
    if s1 and not inverted and s1[0] in s2:
        yield from superpose(s2,s1,True)
    if not s2: return
    if inverted and s2[0] not in s1:
        yield s1+s2;return
    for i,v1 in enumerate(s1):
        if v1 != s2[0]: continue
        yield from (s1[:i+1] + sp for sp in superpose(s1[i+1:],s2[1:],True))
```

output:

```
s1=[1,2,4,4]
s2=[4,4,9,7]

for sp in superpose(s1,s2): print(sp)

[1, 2, 4, 4, 9, 7]
[1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 9, 7]

for sp in superpose(s2,s1): print(sp) # insensitive to parameter order

[1, 2, 4, 4, 9, 7]
[1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 9, 7]

s1 = [1,2,3]
s2 = [2,4,1,6,2]
for sp in superpose(s1,s2): print(sp)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 2]
[2, 4, 1, 6, 2, 3]
```

If you need to find the shortest one, the generator can easily be fed to the min function:

```
min(superpose(s1,s2),key=len)    

[1, 2, 4, 4, 9, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a simpler solution than this:

```
def f(s1, s2):
    indexes = []
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        seq_len = len(s1) - I
        if seq_len < len(s2) and s1[i:] == s2[:seq_len]:
            indexes.append(i)
    return indexes
```

And one-liner, if you like to live on the edge:

```
indexes = [i for i in range(len(s1)) if len(s1)-i>len(s2) and s1[i:]==s2[:len(s1)-i]]
```